# Why does this improper prior = constant?

Tags: bayesian, inference, poisson-distribution, laplace-approximation

[MacKay has an exercise](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itprnn/ps/341.342.pdf) on using Laplace's method for a Poisson model:

$$
p(r \mid \lambda ) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^r}{r!}, \qquad p(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}
$$

And he asks the reader to make a Laplace approximation of the posterior over $\log \lambda$. In a parenthetical, he writes, "Note the improper prior transforms to $P(\log \lambda) = \text{constant}$".

Why is this true? $\log$ is a convex function, and it's not clear why $\frac{1}{\log \lambda}$ can be ignored when maximizing the function. Is it because the function is undefined for negative values?

Comment: Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables you'll find that the pdf of $\ln \lambda$ is uniform.

Comment: As is often the case, confusion arises because the differential element is not made explicit.  The "improper prior" is the measure $\mathrm{d}\lambda/\lambda = \mathrm{d}\log(\lambda).$  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Think Jacobian if it helps.